# How to both implement deserialize and derive it

Tags: rust, serde

I have a `struct Foo` which I want to be serialised as a single two-part string in JSON, e.g. `"01abcdef:42"`, but as normal in bincode.

(I need it to be serialized normally in bincode for size reasons.  In some cases `Bar` or `Baz` are large arrays of bytes which take up more than twice the space in hex.)

My current code does just what I want:

```
pub struct Foo {     
        pub bar: Bar,
        pub baz: Baz
}

impl<'de> ::serde::Deserialize<'de> for Foo {
        fn deserialize<D: ::serde::Deserializer<'de>>(d: D) -> Result<Foo, D::Error> {
                use ::serde::de::Error;
                use core::str::FromStr;

                if d.is_human_readable() {
                        let sl: &str = ::serde::Deserialize::deserialize(d)?;
                        Foo::from_str(sl).map_err(D::Error::custom)
                } else {
                        let clone: FooClone = FooClone::deserialize(d)?;
                        Ok(Foo { bar: clone.bar, baz: clone.baz })
                }
        }
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct FooClone {           
        pub bar: Bar,
        pub baz: Baz
}
```

I need to manually maintain `FooClone` as an identical copy of `Foo`.

I have read [this](https://serde.rs/deserialize-struct.html) but that have significantly more code to maintain than this struct clone.

How can I both manually implement `Deserialize` (to handle the JSON two-part string) and yet derive `Deserialize` for the *same* struct (to eliminate `FooClone`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work. You still use the derive to generate a `deserialize` function. But since it is a remote derive the type will not implement `Deserialize`, but gain an inherent function, which you can call inside the manual `Deserialize` implementation.

```rust
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
#[serde(remote = "Self")]
pub struct Foo {
    pub bar: Bar,
    pub baz: Baz,
}

impl<'de> ::serde::Deserialize<'de> for Foo {
    fn deserialize<D: ::serde::Deserializer<'de>>(d: D) -> Result<Foo, D::Error> {
        use ::serde::de::Error;
        use core::str::FromStr;

        if d.is_human_readable() {
            let sl: &str = ::serde::Deserialize::deserialize(d)?;
            Foo::from_str(sl).map_err(D::Error::custom)
        } else {
            Foo::deserialize(d)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks really good, but even with `use serde` I get: `error: cannot find attribute 'serde' in this scope` on the second line.

Comment: Did you check all the steps to use the serde derive? https://serde.rs/derive.html
My code compiles on the playground.

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten to add the `Deserialize` back into the `#[derive(...` in my code.  All working now.  Thanks for your help.